# How to calculate this limit? Is it possible to use L'Hopital's rule?

Tags: limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x \to -2}\frac{(x-6)^{\frac{1}{3}}+2}{x+2}$$

### Update

What is wrong with WolframAlpha then?
As it states that this limit does not exist [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20x-%3E-2%20%28%28x%20-%206%29**%28%281%29%2F3%29%20%2B%202%29%2F%28x%20%2B%202%29).

Comment: Of course you can use L'Hopital's Rule and you will get the answer immediately. Where exactly is your difficulty?

Comment: I think what Wolfram Alpha is doing, is that it's considering the absolute value of the cube root. It's because fractional powers of negative numers don't generally behave nicely. That's why one has to be very careful when it comes to $\sqrt[3]{\ldots}$ vs $(\ldots)^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-2}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x-6}+2}{x+2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow-2}\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{(x-6)^2}}=\frac{1}{12}.$$
Without:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-2}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x-6}+2}{x+2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow-2}\frac{x-6+8}{(x+2)(\sqrt[3]{(x-6)^2}-2\sqrt[3]{x-6}+4)}=\frac{1}{12}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "fancy", non-Hospital way, to evaluate the limit: let us only basic, though somewhat cumbersome, factoring.

From $\;a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)\iff a+b=\cfrac{a^3+b^3}{a^2-ab+b^2}\;$ , when we assume nothing is divided by zero, we get:

$$x+2=\left(x^{1/3}\right)^3-\left(2^{1/3}\right)^3=\left(x^{1/3}+2^{1/3}\right)\left(x^{2/3}-x^{1/3}2^{1/3}+2^{2/3}\right)$$

and likewise:

$$(x-6)^{1/3}+2=(x-6)^{1/3}+8^{1/3}=\frac{(x-6)+8}{(x-6)^{2/3}-8^{1/3}(x-6)^{1/3}+8^{2/3}}=$$

$$=\frac{x+2}{(x-6)^{2/3}-8^{1/3}(x-6)^{1/3}+8^{2/3}}$$

So we finally get that

$$\frac{(x-6)^{1/3}+2}{x+2}=\frac1{(x-6)^{2/3}-8^{1/3}(x-6)^{1/3}+8^{2/3}}\xrightarrow[x\to-2]{}\frac1{(-8)^{2/3}-8^{1/3}\cdot(-8)^{/13}+8^{2/3}}=$$

$$=\frac1{4-2\cdot(-2)+4}=\frac1{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

Deriv of top is $(1/3)(x-6)^{(-2/3)}$ and of bottom is $1$. So no problem to use Lopital.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say no, you can't use l'Hopital. This limit *is* the derivative of $(x-6)^{1/3}$ at $x=-2$, by definition of the derivative. If you don't already know this limit, how would you differentiate the numerator?

More concretely, if you try to apply l'Hopital, and use the definition of the derivative to do the calculations, the denominator becomes $1$, and the numerator turns into $$\lim_{x\to-2}\frac{(x-6)^{1/3}+2}{x-2}$$ So technically, you can use l'Hopital (the requirements of the theorem are fulfilled), but it won't help you progress at all.

Instead, since this limit is a derivative, I suggest you use more general derivative rules, like the derivative of $x^{1/3}$ and the chain rule, to find this derivative, and thus your answer.

Comment: I agree with you...yet **formally** L'Hospital can be used here as the conditions for its use are fulfilled. From an educative or "don't be a wise guy and to things as they're intended" - point of view I'd write clearly, to avoid wrong interpretations, that it is forbidden to use L'H, indeed.

Comment: @DonAntonio You're right. l'Hopital is _allowed_. But if you're careful and rigorous, it _doesn't help you_. That's what my second paragraph was meant to clarify. Saying "you can't use l'Hopital" can be taken to have two meanings. I meant the less strict one, but I could've been clearer about that.